# Defining Experiment

Tags: probability, sampling-theory

I was referring  to my probability notes and came upon this note :
                  Mutually exclusive events are choosen when events are raken from same experiment and independency is used when events are taken from different expeiments.

So if I toss two coins then the result of first toss and second toss is independent.Does that mean the first toss and second toss are different experiments?This is getting confusing for me because I  always thought those two tosses to be of same experiment as we know the outcomes of this experiment even though we are not perfectly sure about the final result .Why do we have to consider them as different experiments and what happens if we don't consider them to be same?

Comment: This is a good conceptual question for basic probability

Comment: Formally, an experiment is a sequence of actions which have an observable result which may or may not be random.  "Flip two fair coins in sequence" is a perfectly valid experiment with outcomes $\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$.  It *could* be thought of as two separate experiments in sequence, but it does not need to be.  The point that the person was perhaps trying to make is the fact that they *could* be thought of as two separate experiments (*which have no influence over one another*).

Comment: The formal definitions: events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if and only if $A\cap B=\emptyset$ (*which implies $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$*).  Meanwhile, $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz So can independent events be from same experiments?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Take for example rolling a single fair four-sided die (*with faces $1,2,3,4$*).  The event $A=\{2,3\}$ (*you rolled a prime number*) is independent to the event $B=\{2,4\}$ (*you rolled an even number*).  To check this, notice $Pr(A)=\frac{2}{4}=Pr(B)$ and $Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{4}=\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{2}{4}=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$

Comment: @JMoravitz But aren't these events from different trials meaning .....will that effect the experiment or we can count it as a single experiment only?

Comment: In situations like flipping multiple coins in sequence, depending on what type of events you are referring to you may choose to think of it as a single experiment, or you may choose to think of it as separate experiments in sequence so long as it makes sense to do so and is convenient to do so.  There are examples where it does not make sense to do that though, for example: Flip two fair coins in sequence, let event $A$ be the event that the first coin shows a head, let event $B$ be the event that the *total* number of heads is even (*i.e. zero or two*).

Comment: In my most recent example, $A$ and $B$ are indeed independent, and you could think of flipping the two coins as separate experiments, however it makes absolutely no sense to do so since event $B$ has to do with the outcomes of *both* coinflips, not just one.  Compare this to $A$ the event that the first coin shows a head and $C$ the event that the second coin shows a head.  In *that* case, it makes plenty of sense to think of them as somehow separate experiments (*but again, is not necessary to think of them as such*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that "independent events are taken from different experiments" is (to me) misleading. Independence is a situation where knowing the results of one experiment doesn't give you any information about another experiment. For example, tossing coins. Tossing a coin once and getting, say, heads, will not tell you anything about what you're likely to toss the second time.

By contrast, consider these two experiments: You have a photometer (a light intensity meter) and a rain gauge; you intend to use these devices to gather weather information. Are the readings of these two devices independent? No, definitely not. If the rain gauge measures a lot of rain, the photometer is likely to measure low light intensity. Do they represent "different experiments"? Yes.

Also, "mutual exclusive" just means that two events cannot happen at the same time. For example, "the coin is heads" and "the coin is tails" are mutually exclusive. Or "there are no clouds in the sky today" and "my house was struck by lightning today" are mutually exclusive.